# How to make gstreamer play audio from binary data

Tags: gtk, gstreamer, glib, vala, gnome-builder

I'm trying to play a sound effect whenever a user presses a button. The sound effect is stored in gresource at `/org/Adiee5Productions/Title/rsc/sound.wav`. I've never used gstreamer before and so far, I've only found a way to play the sound from URI, which isn't an option here. What could I do to play the sound from binary data extracted by `resources_open_stream()` or `resources_lookup_data()` functions?

The [Vala Documentation](https://valadoc.org/gio-2.0/GLib.Resource.html) mentioned something about `resource://` URI, so I tried passing it into the playbin, but it doesn't seem to work. Any help would be apreciated.